# New close options

Tags: support

I have two questions about the new closing format:

- when will it kick in for us
- how do we list out the site-specific close reasons that we want the system to offer users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has kicked in. Moderators can edit the off-topic close reasons list.